# can’t recollect the word corresponding to “most important or significant work of your life”

Tags: word-request

I was reading up the meanings for modus operandi, modus vivendi, carpe diem and words like such. There was this one word that meant “the most significant work of ones lifetime”. I can't recollect. If anyone relates and remembers, please comment.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking of the Latin term [**magnum opus**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magnum_opus), lit. "great work."